# Positioning scrollbar at the bottom on the screen, and align column

Tags: html, css

The first column has to stay on page when you scroll horizontal as it is now, but how do I make the content behind it, start next to the column instead of under it? When I try to do it, the first column don't follow when I'm scrolling horizontal.

My next question is, how do I make the horizontal scrollbar visible to the user, because right now it's at the bottom of the div, but it has to be visible all the time.

```css
.TestRFloatL {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #114A7A;
}

.outer {
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: visible;
}

#testjobTable {
  margin: auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border: 0px solid black;
}

#testjobTable td {
  text-align: left;
  /* padding: 2px; */
  border: 1px solid white;
}

#testjobTable img {
  width: 20px;
  /*30% var den før Week 40*/
  height: auto;
}

/*table descriptions*/
#header {
  background-color: #114A7A;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
}

#testjobTable th {
  text-align: left;
}

#testjobTable th:nth-child(1) {
  width: 300px;
}

#testjobTable td:hover {
  background-color: #EFF0F1;
}

#testjobTable tr:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
}

#testjobTable td {
  /* padding: 1px; */
  border: 0px solid white;
  border-collapse: collapse;
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <table id='testjobTable'>
      <tr id='header'>
        <th class="TestRFloatL">Col1</th>
        <th>Col2</th>
        <th>Col3</th>
        <th>Col4</th>
        <th>Col5</th>
        <th>Col6</th>
        <th>Col7</th>
        <th>Col8</th>
        <th>Col9</th>
        <th>Col10</th>
        <th>Col11</th>
        <th>Col12</th>
        <th>Col13</th>
        <th>Col14</th>
        <th>Col15</th>
        <th>Col16</th>
        <th>Col17</th>
        <th>Col18</th>
        <th>Col19</th>
        <th>Col20</th>
        <th>Col21</th>
        <th>Col22</th>
        <th>Col23</th>
        <th>Col24</th>
        <th>Col25</th>
        <th>Col26</th>
        <th>Col27</th>
        <th>Col28</th>
        <th>Col29</th>
        <th>Col30</th>
        <th>Col31</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="TestRFloatL"><a href="#">The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </a></td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="TestRFloatL"><a href="#">The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </a></td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="TestRFloatL"><a href="#">The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </a></td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      </tr>
      <td class="TestRFloatL"><a href="#">The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </a></td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      </tr>
      <td class="TestRFloatL"><a href="#">The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </a></td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      </tr>
      <td class="TestRFloatL"><a href="#">The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </a></td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      </tr>
      <td class="TestRFloatL"><a href="#">The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </a></td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      </tr>
      <td class="TestRFloatL"><a href="#">The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </a></td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      </tr>
      <td class="TestRFloatL"><a href="#">The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </a></td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      </tr>
      <td class="TestRFloatL"><a href="#">The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </a></td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      </tr>
      <td class="TestRFloatL"><a href="#">The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </a></td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want, I added `margin-left:300px` to `#testjobTable`

```
#testjobTable {
  margin: auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border: 0px solid black;
  margin-left:300px;
}
```

To make the scrollbar visible I added height of `97vh` to `.inner` div

```
.inner {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: visible;
  height: 97vh;
}
```

```css
.TestRFloatL {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #114A7A;
}

.outer {
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: visible;
  height: 97vh;
}

#testjobTable {
  margin: auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border: 0px solid black;
  margin-left:300px;
}

#testjobTable td {
  text-align: left;
  /* padding: 2px; */
  border: 1px solid white;
}

#testjobTable img {
  width: 20px;
  /*30% var den før Week 40*/
  height: auto;
}


/*table descriptions*/

#header {
  background-color: #114A7A;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
}

#testjobTable th {
  text-align: left;
}

#testjobTable th:nth-child(1) {
  width: 300px;
}

#testjobTable td:hover {
  background-color: #EFF0F1;
}

#testjobTable tr:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
}

#testjobTable td {
  /* padding: 1px; */
  border: 0px solid white;
  border-collapse: collapse;
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <table id='testjobTable'>
      <tr id='header'>
        <th class="TestRFloatL">Col1</th>
        <th>Col2</th>
        <th>Col3</th>
        <th>Col4</th>
        <th>Col5</th>
        <th>Col6</th>
        <th>Col7</th>
        <th>Col8</th>
        <th>Col9</th>
        <th>Col10</th>
        <th>Col11</th>
        <th>Col12</th>
        <th>Col13</th>
        <th>Col14</th>
        <th>Col15</th>
        <th>Col16</th>
        <th>Col17</th>
        <th>Col18</th>
        <th>Col19</th>
        <th>Col20</th>
        <th>Col21</th>
        <th>Col22</th>
        <th>Col23</th>
        <th>Col24</th>
        <th>Col25</th>
        <th>Col26</th>
        <th>Col27</th>
        <th>Col28</th>
        <th>Col29</th>
        <th>Col30</th>
        <th>Col31</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="TestRFloatL"><a href="#">The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </a></td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="TestRFloatL"><a href="#">The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </a></td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="TestRFloatL"><a href="#">The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </a></td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
        <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      </tr>
      <td class="TestRFloatL"><a href="#">The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </a></td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      </tr>
      <td class="TestRFloatL"><a href="#">The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </a></td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      </tr>
      <td class="TestRFloatL"><a href="#">The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </a></td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      </tr>
      <td class="TestRFloatL"><a href="#">The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </a></td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      </tr>
      <td class="TestRFloatL"><a href="#">The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </a></td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      </tr>
      <td class="TestRFloatL"><a href="#">The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </a></td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      </tr>
      <td class="TestRFloatL"><a href="#">The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </a></td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      </tr>
      <td class="TestRFloatL"><a href="#">The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </a></td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      <td>The brown fox is mad jumping all over the place for no reason </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Almost the only thing missing is that col1 souldn't follow then you scroll vertical, only horizontal. I have a long list in front of each row in column1, you can see that in my example that the rows in column 1 stay in front of that row